# Updated the UserCreationForm and now cannot register

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I needed the change the language of the user registration form in Django and created my own but now when I try to register a random person I am getting the

http://127.0.0.1:8180/register/submit error.

forms.py

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    Isim = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    Email = forms.EmailField()
    Mesaj = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)


class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("Şifreler aynı değil"),
    }
    email = forms.EmailField(label="E-Posta Adresi")
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Şifre"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Tekrar şifre"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=_("Lütfen aynı şifreyi girin"))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def clean_email(self):
        if User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Vermiş olduğunuz mail adresiyle bir kayıt bulunmaktadır.")
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            messages.success(request, f'{email} adına hesap oluşturulmuştur! Giriş yapabilirsiniz!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    context = {
        "footer": Footer.objects.filter(name="Generic").first(),
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'member/register.html', context)
```

urls. py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required




urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='member-home'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='member-register'),
    path('giris/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='member/login.html'), name = 'login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='member/logout.html'), name = 'logout'),
    path('forgot-password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='member/forgot-password.html'), name = 'member-forgot-password'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name = 'profile'),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='member/login.html')),
    path('groups/', views.groups, name='member-group'),
    path('groups/<slug:slug>/', views.groups_detail, name='member-group-detail'),
    path('p/<slug:slug>/', views.custom_page, name='custom-page'),
    # path('', views.contact_us, name='member-contact-us'),
    # path('contact-us/', views.contact_us, name='member-contact-us'),
    path('api/', views.apiOverview, name='api-overview'),
    path('sikca-sorulan-sorular/', views.faq, name = 'member-faq'),
    path('uyelik-sozlesmesi/', views.terms, name = 'member-terms'),
    path('not-found/', views.not_found, name = 'member-not-found'),
    path('djrichtextfield/', include('djrichtextfield.urls')),

]
```

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Kayıt Ol</title>
    {% include '../partials/meta.html' %}
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">
  <div class="site-wrap">
    {% include '../partials/header.html' with regular=True %}
      <div class="full-bg" style="" data-aos="fade" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" id="anasayfa">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center text-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card-trans text-primary" style="position:relative; top=15px;">
                <form action="submit" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <div class="h1 mb-4">Kayıt Ol</div>
                        <div class="form text-left">
                            {{form|crispy}}
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                <div class="row align-items-center text-center justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center text-center justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <small><a href="/giris">Giriş Yap</a></small>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <span>
                      Üyelik oluşturduğunuzda<a href="/terms">üyelik sözleşmesini</a> okuduğunuzu ve kabul ettiğinizi onaylıyorsunuz.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      



      {% include '../partials/footer.html' %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, any tip on how to change the button language as?
thanks all
Onur

Comment: You can't just add new fields ('password1', 'password2') to the default User model through the ModelForm, you have to create a CustomUser model in addition to the customized Registration form. Showing how to do this is beyond the scope of this response, and there are numerous tutorials online showing how it's done.

Comment: ah okay so I'll have to create a model and migrate it as well? I have been trying to find one for hours, do you know any videos that can help me out? thanks for your response! Also I actually did not add new fields I created my own one

Comment: I use articles, not videos, personally; I'm sure a youtube search will have many results. Here is a good, straight-forward article: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model